# Undecidable problems not Turing-complete?

Tags: computability, turing-machines, halting-problem

are there systems whose nontrivial properties can't be decided by Turing machines, but for which a Turing machine with an oracle able to find out these properties isn't able to solve the Halting problem (for ordinary TMs)?

Comment: I think this question is not research-level. Voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: I think this is an okay question, although the wording is a little confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there are intermediate degrees.  One way to see this is that there are computably enumerable sets that are Turing incomparable.  See https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Turing_degree for some basic information.